# How to randomly render an array of objects with React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, random

I'm new to React and I'm having problems trying to render an object from an array through its id. I mean, I'm trying to generate a random number and compare this number with the id of an object from an array and render its full pack of items.

This is my App.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import RandomAlbums from './RandomAlbums';


class App extends Component {
  render(){
    const albums = [
      {id: 1, cover: './Covers/Disintegration.jpg', band: "The Cure", title: "Disintegration"},
      {id: 2, cover: './Covers/In_A_Silent_way.jpg', band: "Miles Davis", title: "In a Silent Way"},
      {id: 3, cover: './Covers/In_Rainbows.jpg', band: "Radiohead", title: "In Rainbows"},
      {id: 4, cover: './Covers/Laughing_Stock.jpg', band: "Talk Talk", title: "Talk Talk"},
      {id: 5, cover: './Covers/The_Mantle.jpg', band: "Agalloch", title: "Tha Mantle"}
  ]

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <RandomAlbums albums={albums} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And this is my (not complete) RandomAlbum.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class RandomAlbums extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: '',
            cover: '',
            band: '',
            title: ''
        };
    }


    getAlbum(albums){
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
      this.setState({id:random})
    }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.getAlbum}>Shuffle</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default RandomAlbums;
```

I just simply want to render a shuffle button, when onClick, I get a random cover whith its Band and Album title.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to show random 1 from the array?

Comment: Well I dont mind to generate a number and compare to the ids of the objects or randomly render an index from the array. I was thinking in the first way but the second is ok to me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can select a random album from the albums variable that you are passing in the props:

```
class RandomAlbums extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: '',
            cover: '',
            band: '',
            title: ''
        };
    }


    getAlbum(){
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
      this.setState({...this.props.albums[random]})
    }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.getAlbum}>Shuffle</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default RandomAlbums;
```

Comment: It definitely works, i also was missing the bindind. Thanks.